# Embedded axis Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So I need to display data as follows: every day for a month I have a set of values obtained in different hours. I want the axis to contain the date but between a date an another I want to have the hours from 00:00 to 24:00. I just could not figure it out. I would be pleased if anyone gives me a hint. So I'm using the following code and I would only like to display the date but not the hours in the axis x.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$Time$,
        ylabel=$Availability (\%)$,
                date coordinates in=x,
                xtick=data,
                xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
                xticklabel=\day. \hour:\minute,
                date ZERO=2014-04-1 00:00,% <- improves precision!
                ]

                 \addplot[color=red,mark=x]
        plot coordinates {
                (2014-04-1 00:00, 100)
                (2014-04-1 02:00, 77)
                (2014-04-1 02:15, 62)
                (2014-04-1 15:00, 62)
                (2014-04-1 15:15, 62)
                (2014-04-1 15:30, 62)
                (2014-04-1 19:00, 62)
                (2014-04-2 07:00, 47)
                (2014-04-2 07:15, 11)
                (2014-04-2 11:00, 11)
                (2014-04-2 11:15, 11)
                (2014-04-2 11:30, 11)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please post your initial idea about the code. It's difficult for us to make up data and code from scratch.

Comment: @percusse I just added the code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way, given that I've understood your request correctly. It is a little bit of work, as each of the hour-ticks has to specified manually.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Time,
        ylabel=Availability (\%),
        date coordinates in=x,
        xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
        xticklabel=\day,
        xtick={2014-04-1, 2014-04-02},
        date ZERO=2014-04-1 00:00,% <- improves precision!
        extra x ticks={%
           2014-04-1 04:00,
           2014-04-1 08:00,
           2014-04-1 12:00,
           2014-04-1 16:00,
           2014-04-1 20:00,
           2014-04-2 04:00,
           2014-04-2 08:00,
           2014-04-2 12:00},
       extra x tick label=\hour:\minute
        ]

     \addplot[color=red,mark=x]
        plot coordinates {
                (2014-04-1 00:00, 100)
                (2014-04-1 02:00, 77)
                (2014-04-1 02:15, 62)
                (2014-04-1 15:00, 62)
                (2014-04-1 15:15, 62)
                (2014-04-1 15:30, 62)
                (2014-04-1 19:00, 62)
                (2014-04-2 07:00, 47)
                (2014-04-2 07:15, 11)
                (2014-04-2 11:00, 11)
                (2014-04-2 11:15, 11)
                (2014-04-2 11:30, 11)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```